# jQueryUI - Accordion - Setting Active using ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, accordion

I've checked a number of sites trying to figure this out. However, I have had no luck and figured I would go ahead and make a post on here.

What I am trying to do is setting the Active Accordion depending on ID. Below, is what I am working with.

jQuery Code:

```
$(function () {
    $("#accordion").accordion({
        collapsible: true,
        header: "h3",
        active: 'h3.content3',
        heightStyle: "content"
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="accordion">
    <h3 class="content1">Content Title</h3>
    <div align="left">
        <p>Content for 1 Goes Here</p>
    </div>

    <h3 class="content2">Content Title</h3>
    <div align="left">
        <p>Content for 2 Goes Here</p>
    </div>

    <h3 class="content3">Content Title</h3>
    <div align="left">
        <p>Content for 3 Goes Here</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I hope I explained it well enough, If not, Let me know. I'll try to help ya.

Comment: I don't get it... what do you want to set active?

Comment: Looks like you need to set a number, not a string: $( ".selector" ).accordion({ active: 2 });

Comment: but it works.. http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/uKzpp/ what version are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set `active` based on the `h3` [index](http://api.jquery.com/index/):

```
active: $('#accordion h3').index($('.content3'))
```

Comment: If that's the only unique identifier, isn't that always 0?

Comment: @ravb79 Are you refering to the index of the `h3`? In the context of `#accordion`, it will be zero based and representing the index of the  selected `h3`

Comment: But aren't you indexing all h3's with class .content3? (Which only exists once)

Comment: @ravb79 it's index in the parent is returned, not the index from the selected elements but because there are more elements in the parent this won't return the right number

Comment: Why does $('#accordion h3.content3').index() give me 4, while .content1 and .content2 give me 0 and 2 respectively? Why does it skip? Does it count the divs as well?

Comment: Thanks very much. This has fixed the issue I was dealing with. Much appreciated for your help guys!